# NumPy change float precision for the array

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

How do I change the float precision for an entire array without having to do `np.set_printoptions`? It is not about printing; I want the values to be compressed to do  equality checks with other arrays.

```
e = np.array([0.8292222222222225, 0.1310000000000003])
```

to

```
e = np.array([0.829225, 0.131003])
```

I want to be able to compare `0.8292222222222225` with `0.829225` in other arrays.

Cannot get equality as `True`

```
>>> e = np.array([0.8292222222222225, 0.1310000000000003]) 
>>> e[0]
0.8292222222222225
>>> e[0]==0.829225
False
>>>
```

Comment: It's not changing the precision, it's removing duplicate numbers.

Comment: Numpy use the standard CPU instructions for the basic comparison of floating-point (FP) values. FP comparisons are standardized by the IEEE-754 standard. The comparison is exact. Thus, if there is one ULP error, it is not true anymore. This behaviour cannot be modified by the user. The only way is not to use a strict FP comparison. By the way, all FP operations are rounded and the default rounding is platform-dependent (though it is always one of the standard IEEE-754 rounding mode). This means you should (nearly) *never compare FP values that way* (unless values are fetched from the array).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) function. It allows you to compare elements within a tolerance:

```
>>> a = np.array([0.8292222222222225, 0.1310000000000003])
>>> b = np.array([0.8293, 0.132])
>>> np.isclose(a, b, atol=1e-3)
array([ True,  True])
>>> np.isclose(a, b, atol=1e-4)
array([ True, False])
>>> np.isclose(a, b, atol=1e-5)
array([False, False])
```

Note that you can use both the relative tolerance and the absolute one.